# Significant Result in Levene's Test

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity, kruskal-wallis-test, levenes-test

I am very confused right now. I ran Levene's test on my data and got a p-value of 0.000, meaning that variances are very heterogeneous. I transformed the data but no method can make them homogeneous. So that's it, ANOVA would be inappropriate to use. I was thinking that my data could be nonparametric so Kruskal-Wallis would be the best test to use. However, when I tried testing the data for Levene's test for nonparametric data, I still got a significant result.

In short, my data failed the Levene's test for both parametric and non-parametric assumption. What do I do now?

Answer (score 3):

None of this follows ineluctably from the evidence you give.

> I ran Levene's test on my data and got a p-value of 0.000, meaning
>   that variances are very heterogeneous.

Possibly so, possibly not. The result is highly significant, but that may just mean that you have a large enough sample size to allow firm rejection of the null. It could be that the difference in variances is not fatal to ANOVA.

```
 I transformed the data but no method can make them homogeneous.
```

Possibly so, possibly not. We can't tell without looking at the data and hearing what you tried. Perhaps you missed out a transformation that would help. (I've seen people try transformations that make their problem worse; that need not be you, but you don't give enough detail for us to be sure.)

> So that's it, ANOVA would be inappropriate to use. I was thinking that
>   my data could be nonparametric so Kruskal-Wallis would be the best
>   test to use. However, when I tried testing the data for Levene's test
>   for nonparametric data, I still got a significant result.

Data are **not** parametric or non-parametric, just techniques. That's a misuse of terminology. See notably [@Glen_b's answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202879/what-are-the-most-misused-statistics-terms-that-we-should-care-to-correct/202915#202915) More crucially, I don't know what Levene's test for nonparametric data means. What makes you think that Kruskal-Wallis requires any such prior test?

I'd recommending that you back up and show us your data, or at least informative graphs, and tell us what interests you about them.