# Why do some people use -999 or -9999 to replace missing values?

Tags: missing-data

I have a dataset. There are lots of missing values. For some columns, the missing value was replaced with -999, but other columns, the missing value was marked as 'NA'.

Why would we use -999 to replace the missing value?

Comment: I have never seen -999 myself. So far I have seen empty strings and NAs.

Comment: Because they want to horribly mess up results for people who do superficial analysis and don't read documentation carefully! (Being serious though, @Stephan Kolassa has the real answer.)

Comment: Ask the person who provided the dataset...?

Comment: Better yet are 999 values in measurement columns to indicate the measurement doesn't apply... at least a -999 or a 0 would have the semantic meaning that it's not a valid/important value.  999 is just the worst.

Comment: I feel like I once read that this was a convention from the days of recording data on punch cards. Knocking out a full row of 9s made the missing data clearly visible when looking at the card since it was literally a "missing row". I can't find a reference to back this up, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is a holdout from earlier times, when computer software stored numerical vectors as numerical vectors. No real number has the semantics "I'm missing". So when early statistical software had to differentiate between "true" numbers and missing values, they put in something that was "obviously" not a valid number, like -999 or -9999.

Of course, that -999 or -9999 stood for a missing value is not "obvious" at all. Quite often, it can certainly be a valid value. Unless you *explicitly* check for such values, you can have all kinds of "interesting" errors in your analyses.

Nowadays, numerical vectors that can contain missing values are internally represented as "enriched" numerical vectors, i.e., numerical vectors with additional information as to which values are missing. This of course is much better, because then missing values will be treated as such and not mistakenly treated as valid.

Unfortunately, some software still uses such a convention, perhaps for compatibility. And some users have soaked up this convention through informal osmosis and enter -999 instead of NA even if their software supports cleanly entering missing values.

Moral: *don't* encode missing values as -999 or -9999.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you.  I know some software still take them as the valid value since -999 is still a number. So how should we deal with this kind dataset? Recover it to null or what? For example, age, Is it possible that take all the null or -999 as a category and bucket the rest of age data into 0-10, 11-20, etc. which means convert the numerical variable to category variable? Is it make any sense? thank you.

Comment: It's one of those tradition that people mistakenly follow without understanding why, and just because it is done before, it doesn't mean it is right to begin with.

Comment: In addition to it being a holdout from earlier times, there are likely people who have never learned that explicit representation of missing values exists, and so, when they need to insert a missing value, figure that the thing to use is some kind of bogus number.

Comment: This is not just a holdout thing.  If I'm writing a tool to do some manipulation of data, reading in columns of numbers is easy in just about any programming language out there. Reading values in, detecting non-numerical values, and parsing them accordingly takes quite a lot more time.  And if you think -9999 mucks with the statistics, my group I work with has developed a love of using 1e32 for invalid values.  Let me tell you what happens to your variance when you do that!

Comment: Great, succint answer. But adding some historical detail might make it an even better answer. Admittedly, that would take some research. :)

Comment: Such encoding might also be used to denote some other kind of measurement error; i.e. "machine wasn't working" vs. "no one was there to make the measurement".

Comment: @qqqwww: it would be best to detect the value used to indicate missingness and convert such entries to true missingness or NA. [Discretization of numerical data is usually not a good idea.](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous)

Comment: @qqqwww: There are any number of reasons why numerical values might be unavailable or inappropriate; so you can't deal with the issue sensibly until you know why. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-data; but it could mean "not applicable" (e.g. spouse's income for an unmarried person), or even *censored* - above (or below) a given threshold.

Comment: @CortAmmon many numerical libraries have a standard way of representing NaN, maybe yours have something like that that you can use? In particular, numpy places nans instead of anything that cannot parse as a number.

Comment: I have seen cases where missing data is represented as -99, -999, 99, 999, or -99.99. In the same file. It is a mess.

Comment: @Davidmh Sadly I am not so lucky.  Our nans include nan NAN NaN 1.#NAN 1.#QNAN 1.#INF and blanks, mostly depending on platform that generated the data.  However, none of the parsers (including the built in ones with the language) actually read the nans they output reliably.

Comment: It's often difficult if not impossible to find out ages of people in traffic accidents handled by the police, for a mix of reasons I leave to your imagination. One police authority in Britain  supposedly used a convention of entering 99 as a missing code. This only came to light when reported averages were implausibly high. That is the story any way.

Answer (score 29):

Such values are for databases.  Most databases long ago, and many today, allocated a fixed number of digits for integer-valued data.  A number like -999 is the smallest that can be stored in four characters, -9999 in five characters, and so on.

(It should go without saying that--by definition--a numeric field cannot store alphanumeric characters such as "NA".  *Some* numeric code has to be used to represent missing or invalid data.)

Why use the most negative number that can be stored to signify a missing value?  *Because if you mistakenly treat it as a valid number, you want the results to be dramatically incorrect.*  The further your codes for missing values get from being realistic, the safer you are, because hugely wrong input usually screws up the output.  (Robust statistical methods are notable exceptions!)

How could such a mistake happen?  This occurs all the time when data are exchanged between systems.  A system that assumes -9999 represents a missing value will blithely output that value when you write the data out in most formats, such as CSV.  The system that reads that CSV file might not "know" (or not be "told") to treat such values as missing.

Another reason is that good statistical data and computing platforms recognize many different kinds of missing values: NaNs, truly missing values, overflows, underflows, non-responses, etc, etc.  By devoting the most negative possible values (such as -9999, -9998, -9997, etc) to these, you make it easy to query out all missing values from any table or array.

Yet another is that such values usually show up in graphical displays as extreme outliers.  Of all the values you could choose to stand out in a graphic, the most negative possible one stands the greatest chance of being far from your data.

---

There are useful implications and generalizations:

- A good value to use for missing data in floating-point fields is the most negative valid number, equal approximately to $-10^{308}$ for double-precision floats.  (Imagine the effect that would have on any average!)  On the same principle, many old programs, which used single-precision floats, used somewhat arbitrary large numbers such as `1E+30` for missing values.
- Adopt  a standard rule of this type to make it easy to invent NoData codes in new circumstances (when you are designing your own database software).
- Design your software and systems to fail dramatically if they fail at all.  The worst bugs are those that are intermittent, random, or tiny, because they can go undetected and be difficult to hunt down.

Comment: Of course, if you're using floats, you can just use `NaN` for missing values. That has no ambiguity about whether it's a valid numeric value or not, and (given that most standard floating-point operations are NaN-propagating) will screw up any calculation that mistakenly treats it as a valid data point even more surely and obviously than, say, $-10^{303}$ would.

Comment: NaN is Not a Number, NA is Not Available at least in R

Comment: In theory IEEE floats support different kinds of NaNs which would work well as tags for different kinds of missing/invalid data. In practice most programming languages lack proper support for distinguishing such NaNs and are prone to losing that extra information.

Comment: Very good except for the sign bit didn't take up any space in the scheme actually used by databases. They would break up into digit pairs of 00-99 and treat those as numbers; but if the number was negative, they would store 255 - # instead of number. Also 127 and 128 were used for +/- inf.

Comment: @Joshua That might be correct for some databases, but definitely was not the case for many others, especially early in the development.  Any database using decimal encoded values could not have used the mechanism you propose, anyway.  An example of an early and widely-used PC database that works the way I described is dBase, eventually offered as the dBase III, Clipper, and FoxPro products (acquired by Microsoft and later abandoned in favor of Access). For fixed field width data interchange formats, the minus sign always occupies a character.

Answer (score 14):

You can use *anything* to encode missing values. Some software, like R, use special values to encode missing data, but there are also software packages, e.g. SPSS, that do not have any special codes for missing data. In the second case you need to make *arbitrary* choice for such values. You can choose *anything*, but generally it is a good idea to choose some value that visibly differs from your data (e.g. your data are percentages in 0-100 range, so you choose 999 for encoding missing data, or your data is human age and you use negative values for missing observations). The idea behind it is that by doing so you should be able to notice if something went wrong and the numbers do not add up.

The problem with such encoding is however that you actually can not notice the special encoding and end up with rubbish results.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, in SPSS, the missing value(s) 999 or whatever IS tagged as a special missing code and handled separately from other values.  It may be tabulated separately or excluded entirely.  A distinction is made from the result of things like zero division or log(0).

Answer (score 2):

Are there computed variables in the dataset? Or is this an analytic dataset that comes form merged / sorted data? Some software uses very large negative values to denote missing data. But other software creates missing values with NA or `.`. When they are discrepant, usually some post processing has led to disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is useful to encode -9999 values instead of NA. I have come across datasets with such encoding where the intent was to clearly define the limits of data for instance on a map.  A quick histogram will reveal these sort of values.