# NA values in numeric values

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a numeric integer feature (i.e, age), with an important number of non-valid values (NA, zeroes...). Not enough to discard the variable. I can't easily impute with estimated values.

What would be a way to manage them? Set the values to an 'impossible', value like 999999? Are some algorithms (Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, SVM...) better than other to deal with them?

In the worst case, the only solution I can imagine is create a model with the rest of the variables to 'predict' the missing one, but I think, I the particular case I'm sudying, It wil not be accurate.

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve, replacing NA values with 999999 won't solve it. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/why-do-some-people-use-999-or-9999-to-replace-missing-values Solutions to missing data range from simply ignoring it (drop instances with NA values) to imputation of NAs to collecting more data. Which one is appropriate in your particular case depends on what you're trying to learn from the data, and how the missingness comes about. Here's a search to get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=na+values+answers%3A1+score%3A3