How to compare the means of two groups when one group is censored
Let's say I have two groups of people and want to compare their height's means.
The second group is right censored.
What hypothesis test should be used to compare the means of these two groups?
I intuitively think that applying a t-test is not the correct approach.
According to these questions:
Inference with only left-censored data
and
Version of Mann-Whitney U test, for right-censored data
survival analysis and the log-rank tests can be used, but both of these cases involve time related data, which is not the case with mine.
In question How to compare values between groups if data is left censored data is hierarchical and no answer has been offered.

Because a sample mean (as well as a population mean) is sensitive to even a single value, a universal test does not exist.  Any effective solution will therefore begin with a fairly strong assumption, such as a parametric distribution assumption.  Do you really have groups of people or are you just using that as a metaphor for your actual problem?  If it's the latter, please tell us what your problem truly is about, for otherwise you are likely to get good answers that don't apply (or, worse, give terrible results for you).

@whuber yes my case really does involve the heights of people. However the distribution is not likely to be parametric in my case (as unintuitive as it might seem). Must non-parametric tests be ruled out?

The more information you can exploit about likely distributions of human heights, the better off you will be.  You don't need to use a procedure designed for the possibility of mile-high people, for instance.  BTW, your use of "parametric" suggests a possible misunderstanding.  Some popular (and very poor) textbooks use this term to mean "Normally distributed," but that's (wildly) incorrect.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163915 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/202915/919 for elaboration.

@whuber from my limited understanding I perceive the term "parametric distribution" to refer to those distributions that have some known characteristics (including but not limited to the normal distribution), hence they allow for the use of "parametric methods" that take advantage of the distribution's known characteristics. In my case the data seem to follow a highly left skewed distribution, something like a Beta distribution of X ~ Beta(20,2), if that helps in any way.
